# laravel 4.2 with reactJs and Redux

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, redux, laravel-4.2

I have wondering is there any way or maybe some tutorial how to implement ReactJS with Redux on Laravel backend application but It is nessesary to be Laravel 4.2 implementation becouse I am using this version of laravel. Does anyone have idea how to implement React to created huge laravel 4.2 application?
Thanks for help.

Comment: If you still have to start the app maybe try the master branch or wait for Laravel 5.5 https://laravel-news.com/frontend-presets it will include scaffolds for React

Comment: You have Laravel's views. You include your javascript there. Job done. Why does there have to be a tutorial? It's just two different technologies. Laravel produces HTML. HTML includes javascript. It's so simple. Do you understand what PHP or JavaScript even are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `Laravel Mix`

It's version/framework independent and all scaffolding is already done for React & Vue.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix

If you dont like using "Webpack". Its ancient brother "Elixir" is always there to help Gulp guys.

Here it is: https://github.com/laravel/elixir

Comment: But is this work with Laravel 4.2 i try to find that information in documentation for laravel-mix but there is only part that laravel-mix support Laravel 5.4. Is there a Backward compatibility to laravel 4.2?

Comment: Mix and Elixir are completely framework independent.
You may use them even in a non-laravel based projects.
The only thing you need to do is to add one of them based on your desire to your `package.json` file as a dependency and using them for your React transpilation.
Take a look at Mix's example project, everything is configurable and there is no laravel dependency for them.